# Clear results on form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function where when the zip code is entered and if there are any entries in city, it clears that field in the form and shows the list of cities.

The same applies when the user enters a city based on a drop down box that contains a list of cities. Once the user selects the city, the zip code field is left blank.

With help of stackoverflow,

I was able to obtain this. However,for some reason, it only works for the zip code field. Meaning, once the field in the city is cleared, I am able to retrieve a list items based on the zip code and keep on changing the zip code. When I select a city, the field for zip code clears but no new results are displayed.

Not sure what is going on.

```js
$('#zip').on('input', function() {
  $('#city').val("")
})
$('#city').on('input', function() {
  $('#zip').val("")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
<!--- <div id="loader" style="position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 100%; background: url('loader.gif') center center #efefef"></div><!--Progress bar--->
  <form name="providerSearch" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
            <option value=""></option><option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option> </select></div>

   <div class="form-group">
             <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
        <option value=""></option>
        <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                           <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select>
                      
            <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>---->
            </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
     <div class="form-group widthLanguage">
              
                      
                    <select name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
      <cfoutput query="Languages">
        <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select>
                      
                      
                      
       <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
         <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
          </select>--->
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
     <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr class="hrDoctor" />
   <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance"><option selected="selected">5</option><option selected="selected">10</option><option selected="selected">15</option><option selected="selected">20</option> </select>

       <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
     <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\-]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
   <!---<div class="form-group buttonWidth resetButton"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="reset" value="Reset"  onClick="window.location.reload()"/></div>--->
  </form>
 <!---</div><!---Progress bar--->--->
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

           $('#zip').on("input",function(){
               $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);

           })

            $('#city').on("change",function(){
               $('#zip').val("");
            })
       })
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-body">
<!--- <div id="loader" style="position: fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height: 100%; background: url('loader.gif') center center #efefef"></div><!--Progress bar--->
  <form name="providerSearch" ng-submit="SearchProvider(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physiciansfirstname" ng-model="searchParam.FirstName" placeholder="First name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="physicianslastname" ng-model="searchParam.LastName" placeholder="Last name:" type="text" /></div>

   <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="providerSpecialty" ng-model="searchParam.Specialty"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Specialty</option>
            <option value=""></option><option>Family practice</option><option>General practice</option><option>Internal medicine</option><option>Pediatrics</option> </select></div>

   <div class="form-group">
             <select name="proCity" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
        <option value=""></option>
        <cfoutput query="cityFind">
                           <option value=#city#>#city#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
             </select>
                      
            <!---<select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option><option ng-repeat="c in Cities">{{c.City}}</option> </select>---->
            </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 no-right-padding paddingLanguage">
     <div class="form-group widthLanguage">
              
                      
                    <select name="language" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
                        <option value=""></option>
      <cfoutput query="Languages">
        <option value=#Language#>#Language#</option>
      </cfoutput> 
       </select>
                      
                      
                      
       <!---<select name="language" class="form-control widthLanguage" id="language" ng-model="searchParam.Language">
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Language</option>
         <option ng-repeat="l in Languages">{{l.Lang}}</option>
          </select>--->
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 no-left-padding">
     <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" name="gender" ng-model="searchParam.Gender">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Gender</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option>Male</option><option>Female</option> </select></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr class="hrDoctor" />
   <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.distance"><option selected="selected">5</option><option selected="selected">10</option><option selected="selected">15</option><option selected="selected">20</option> </select>

       <div class="input-group-addon">mi</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
     <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\-]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
   <!---<div class="form-group buttonWidth resetButton"><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="reset" value="Reset"  onClick="window.location.reload()"/></div>--->
  </form>
 <!---</div><!---Progress bar--->--->
 </div>
</div>

        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               
               $('#zip').on("input",function(){
                   $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);
                   
               })
               
                $('#city').on("change",function(){
                   $('#zip').val("");
                })
           })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result describe in the question. I do have a question: do you feel that maybe the id "city" might be the issue?

Comment: @RobertoFlores , when click on Run code snippet , how is result?

Comment: @ ehsan: Yes it is workin on the snippet, however, when I try to do it on my end, it does not allow for the new results to show if I select a city

Comment: @ ehsan:  However, if I enter a zip code and the city selection has been made, I am able to see the new locations based on the zip entry

Comment: @RobertoFlores, copy all my answer and paste in your editor and try it.

Comment: @ ehsan: I did and that is why I am letting you know it still performs the same results as before

Comment: @ ehsan: I have a question: how would I resubmit the form when I select a new city. I feel it does not recognize that the zip code field is blank